# Populating a textbox from clicking in a table row

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help to populate a textbox when I click in my table line.

Here's my code

```
<script>
    function moveNumbers(number){
        document.getElementById("teste").value=number;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table" style="width: 600px; height: 100px; overflow-x:auto">
<table id="listeqpt">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>VAD</th>
    <th>Date Added</th>
  </tr>

    {% for i in vlist %}
   <tr>
       <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">{{ i.eqpttype }}</td>
       <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">{{ i.serialnumber }}</td>
       <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">{{ i.vad }}</td>
       <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.value)">{{ i.dateadded }}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
<form name="teste">
    <input id="teste" type="text">
</form>
```

With this code, I'm getting 'undefined' value in my textbox (and by the way, i need to populate one textbox with each information that i have in my table, so in this example 4 textboxes)

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `moveNumbers(this.innerText.trim())`

Comment: i would not suggest innerText as it is nonstandart: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText

Answer (score 1):

Updated your code to exclude templating stuff, but anyways, `td` elements don't have a `value` property. you just need to get the `textContent` and for good measure, use `trim()` to remove white space:

---

UPDATED CODE 11/9 Based on clarifying comment

```html
<script>
    function moveNumbers(index, number){
        document.getElementById("teste" + index).value  = number;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table" style="width: 600px; height: 100px; overflow-x:auto">
<table id="listeqpt">
    <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>VAD</th>
    <th>Date Added</th>
    </tr>

    
    <tr>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 1 cell 1</td>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 1 cell 2</td>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 1 cell 3</td>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 1 cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 2 cell 1</td>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 2 cell 2</td>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 2 cell 3</td>
        <td onclick="moveNumbers(this.cellIndex, this.textContent.trim())">row 2 cell 4</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
<form name="teste">
    <input id="teste0" type="text">
    <input id="teste1" type="text">
    <input id="teste2" type="text">
    <input id="teste3" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, with your example I'm getting one field from my table on click. Actually I need to click in the line and populate different text boxes. Using your example, once I click in the line i have to populate each text box with a different number: teste with 1, teste1 with 2, teste3 with 3 and so on.

Comment: So currently you have a single input. Do you want each click to generate a new input containing the clicked td's value? I'm not entirely understanding what it is you want to do.

Comment: I'll try to explain in another way, basically what i want is to click in a line from my table (which has 4 columns) and onclick, populate four text boxes with each column's value. In this example, I'm working with 1 line, but this table is populated from my mongodb which is going to have more than one document.

Comment: Updated the code to do what I _think_ you were looking for. Or at least hope that this will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: We are close now....With that code, when I click in the table cell it fills the right text box but my need is to click in the row and then fill the text boxes with the right cell values. I believe that the onclick event needs to be in <tr> tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I was looking for... check the code below:

```
<script>
    function moveNumbers(number){
        var Row = document.getElementById(number.toString());
        var cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        document.getElementById("teste0").value=cells[0].innerText;
        document.getElementById("teste1").value=cells[1].innerText;
        document.getElementById("teste2").value=cells[2].innerText;
        document.getElementById("teste3").value=cells[3].innerText;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="table" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; overflow-x:auto">
<table id="listeqpt">
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>VAD</th>
    <th>Date Added</th>
  </tr>
    {% set count = 1 %}
     {% for i in vlist %}
    <tr id={{ count }} onclick="moveNumbers(this.id)">
        <td>{{ i.eqpttype }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.serialnumber }} </td>
        <td>{{ i.vad }}</td>
        <td>{{ i.dateadded }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
<form name="teste">
    <input id="teste0" type="text">
    <input id="teste1" type="text">
    <input id="teste2" type="text">
    <input id="teste3" type="text">
</form>
```

Thanks for helping me with this....See ya